# Display some words after that my application found something

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have an application in Jade using Node.js. This has an array of items and I do an if and looks for a word, but now I need display 3 words after the word that I found.

Here is part of my code:

```
td #{item.content}
if item.content.includes('Enviado el')
```

I don't know how display that with this?

Comment: Please describe more what you need to do and more code if possible

Comment: Please refer to - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and consider updating your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? This will conditionally display additional text within the `td`.

(Note: you'll need two spaces before your additional text if you want a space between it and the value of `item.content`)

```
td
  | #{item.content}
  if item.content.includes('Enviado el')
    |  your three words
```